# how is capsule.properties supposed to toggle between prod and dev?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My Bixby capsule.properties is currently set up like so:

```
capsule.config.mode=default
```

And I have distinct dev/prod config/secrets set up and the values look correct to me. But despite double-checking the values on submission to marketplace the credentials are failing in prod.  Is there an example of how the capsule.properties is supposed to be set up to account for different dbs in dev & prod?

Among other things, I am confused by the properties precedence explanation in https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/capsule-config#property-precedence, which seems to say that it will grab dev first regardless whether it's in prod or dev.

Comment: can someone please try running altbrains.workshop in prod?  I noticed that I had a miscapitalization in the value of altbrainsbaseUrl in prod config and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding capsule.properties:

It is not used to select DEV or PROD. I would think it is more like a final fallback place for capsule to look for a property when config.get() failed to fetch info from DEV or PROD.

Regarding Property Precedence:

In case of IDE sync or revision override of private submission, or on-device testing with private submission:
DEV > PROD > capsule.properties

In case of marketplace capsule, revision override of public submission, or on-device testing with public submission: 
PROD > capsule.properties

Basically, DEV is not visible when dealing with public submission.